# How to bind ONLY ASCII keys in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, key-bindings

I want to bind only ASCII keys using tkinter.
I know how to bind it selectively (per key) or even by binding it to all keyboard keys (by using `<Key>` or `<KeyPress>`), but problem is, I don't know how to do the same for every ASCII keys.

Here is what I tried so far:

1. Using `<Key>` or `<KeyPress>` binding for catching all keyboard keys (doesn't support mouse keys):

```py
import tkinter as tk

def key_press(event):
    label.config(text = f'char Pressed: {event.char!r}')
    label2.config(text=f'keysym Pressed: {event.keysym!r}')

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text='Press a key')
label2 = tk.Label(root, text='Press a key')
label.pack()
label2.pack()
root.bind('<Key>', key_press)
root.mainloop()
```

2. Using per key binding (need to know the name/keysym first, as seen on the [tkinter documentation](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/key-names.html)):

```py
import tkinter as tk

def key_press(event):
    label.config(text = f'char Pressed: {event.char!r}')
    label2.config(text=f'keysym Pressed: {event.keysym!r}')

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text='Press a key')
label2 = tk.Label(root, text='Press a key')
label.pack()
label2.pack()
# here we only use the K and BackSpace key as example
root.bind('<BackSpace>', key_press)
root.bind('<K>', key_press)
root.mainloop()
```

How can I bind a function only to all ascii keys using just tkinter? (no third-party module if possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and efficient solution to bind only [ascii chars](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/ASCII.html) in my opinion is to use [event.char](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L1643).
`event.char` corresponds to [`%A`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/bind.html#M42)
and will be an empty string if no *printable* character is parsed.
To access the individual character you can use [repr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr)
as it is [implemented in tkinter](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L256)

I did not used `event.keycode` because for *Multi_key* they seem unreliable.
Also included `del`-key but found no better way as to use `keysym` for it, feel free to find a better way

Example code:

```
import tkinter as tk

def isascii(event):
    if event.char != '':
        char = list(event.char)[0] #'^' or '`' is only parsed as doubles in Windows
        if ord(char) <= 127: #avoid non-ascii like '²' or '³' or '´'
            print(
                repr(char), #printable character
                ord(char) #corresponding ascii value
                )
    elif event.keysym == 'Delete':
        print('backspace / delete', 127)

root = tk.Tk()
root.bind('<Key>', isascii)
root.mainloop()
```

compressed version:

```
import tkinter as tk

def isascii(event):
    if event.char != '' and ord((char := list(event.char)[0])) <= 127:
        print(
            repr(char), #printable character
            ord(char) #corresponding ascii value
            )
    elif event.keysym == 'Delete': print('delete', 127)

root = tk.Tk()
root.bind('<Key>', isascii)
root.mainloop()
```